# In gnuplot, how do you change the number of points when plotting a function

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to plot a cosine function over a lot of periods

However, the output is very scribbly, because gnuplot uses a low number of points to plot a function. Is there any way to adjust this to include more points?

[Output that shows a blocky cosine-function due to low sampling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VINm1.png)

This is my very minimal code:

```
set xrange [0:50]
plot cos(x) with linespoints
```

I tried googling for the answer but I could not find any way to set the number of points when plotting a function. Is there any way to adjust this to include more points, apart from generating my own data table in excel or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't believe that you haven't found anything searching the web. This is really a RT*M question: (check `help samples`).

For example:

```
set samples 500
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As to how I didn't find anything, I did not think of "sample" as the keyword and just got very frustrated searching for "set number of points" etc. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DonLouigi I know it is difficult to search for it if you don't know how it is called. Never mind! Now, other people will hopefully find it if they search for something similar to your question title.